# Outlook - Prompt for confirmation before permanently deleting items - greyed out

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

Microsoft 365 Apps for Enterprise (16.0.13029.20344)
Outlook
Prompt for confirmation before permanently deleting items (option greyed out)

How do we reenable this option?

[image]

We can find no way to do this via group policy, O365 app settings, or registry.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I also searched a lot but could not found specific registry key related to this.
According to my test, we could successfully reset this settings via the steps below, for your reference:

1. Exit Outlook and open the Registry Editor
2. Navigate to: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0
3. Right-click the Outlook folder
4. Rename it as Outlook1
5. Restart your Outlook and add your email account to test

(Note: Serious problems can occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Before making changes, back up the registry to restore it in case something goes wrong.)

Hope this could help.